# stringstream operator << for a template type

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, stl

I have the following code:

```
template <class T>
static std::string ToString(const T& t)
{
  stringstream temp;
  temp << t;
  return temp.str();
}
```

It compiles with no problems with Visual C++ on Windows, but when trying to compile it with GCC on Linux I get the following error:

```
no match for 'operator<<' in 'temp << t'
```

What could be the reason for that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That depends on the type `T`. What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the type T as Space_C0wb0y said.

Check out the following code

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
static std::string ToString(const T& t){
  std::stringstream temp;
  temp << t;
  return temp.str();
}
struct empty{};
struct non_empty{
  std::string str;
  non_empty(std::string obj):str (obj){}
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const non_empty &x);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const non_empty &x){
    out << x.str;
    return out;
}

int main(){
   std::string s = ToString<double>(12.3); // this will work fine
 /*********************************************************************************
  * std::string k = ToString(empty()); // no match for 'operator<<' in 'temp << t'*
  *********************************************************************************/
   std::string t = ToString(non_empty("123")); // this works too

}
```

A call to `ToString(empty());` gives the same error that you have got but `ToString(non_empty("123"));` is [fine](http://ideone.com/3VON5). What does that imply?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're just missing the `#include<sstream>` from the top of your file.

This would explain why identical code could compile on Windows, because of differences between the standard headers.

This was the solution in my case, when using the template with the type `const char*`.